# Why doesn't my custom recipes run on AWS OpsWorks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

I've created a GitHub repo for my simple custom recipe:

```
my-cookbook/
|- recipes/
   |- appsetup.rb
```

I've added the repo to Custom Chef Recipes as `https://github.com/my-github-user/my-github-repo.git`

I've added `my-cookbook::appsetup` to the Setup "cycle".

I know it's executed, because it fails to load if I mess up the syntax.

This is my appsetup.rb:

```
node[:deploy].each do |app_name, deploy|
  script "install_composer" do
    interpreter "bash"
    user "root"
    cwd "#{deploy[:deploy_to]}/current"
    code "curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php && php composer.phar install --no-dev"
  end
end
```

When I log into the instance by SSH with the ubuntu user, composer isn't installed.

I've also tried the following to no avail (A nodejs install):

```
node[:deploy].each do |app_name, deploy|
  execute "installing node" do
    command "add-apt-repository --yes ppa:chris-lea/node.js && apt-get update && sudo apt-get install python-software-properties python g++ make nodejs"
  end
end
```

Node doesn't get installed, and there are no errors in the log. The only references to the cookbook in the log just says:

```
[2014-03-31T13:26:04+00:00] INFO: OpsWorks Custom Run List: ["opsworks_initial_setup", "ssh_host_keys", "ssh_users", "mysql::client", "dependencies", "ebs", "opsworks_ganglia::client", "opsworks_stack_state_sync", "mod_php5_apache2", "my-cookbook::appsetup", "deploy::default", "deploy::php", "test_suite", "opsworks_cleanup"]
...
2014-03-31T13:26:04+00:00] INFO: New Run List expands to ["opsworks_initial_setup", "ssh_host_keys", "ssh_users", "mysql::client", "dependencies", "ebs", "opsworks_ganglia::client", "opsworks_stack_state_sync", "mod_php5_apache2", "my-cookbook::appsetup", "deploy::default", "deploy::php", "test_suite", "opsworks_cleanup"]
...
[2014-03-31T13:26:05+00:00] DEBUG: Loading Recipe my-cookbook::appsetup via include_recipe
[2014-03-31T13:26:05+00:00] DEBUG: Found recipe appsetup in cookbook my-cookbook
```

Am I missing some critical step somewhere? The recipe is clearly recognized and loaded, but doesn't seem to be executed.

(The following are fictitious names: my-github-user, my-github-repo, my-cookbook)

Answer (score 3):

I know you've abandoned the cookbook but I'm almost 100% sure it's because you don't have a `metadata.rb` file in the root of your cookbook.

Comment: Thank you, that will hopefully be helpful to anyone else (or me if I try it again)

Comment: This was my problem and adding the file worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your cookbook name should not contain a dash. I had the same problem, replacing by '_' solved it for me.

Comment: Thank you, I've abandoned the cookbooks since this question was asked, so I can't verify if this solved my problem or not, unfortunately!

Answer (score 0):

If those commands are failing silently, it could be that your use of && is obscuring a failure.

As for add-apt-repository, that is an interactive command. Try using the "--yes" option to answer yes by default, making it no longer interactive.

Comment: Thanks, I tried forking https://github.com/onema/opsworks-chef-cookbooks, then used that instead, with composer::install (https://github.com/onema/opsworks-chef-cookbooks/blob/master/composer/recipes/install.rb) in the Setup-cycle and that didn't do anything either unfortunately, so I assume something else is amiss apart from the &&:s.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not execute your command successfully, you will not find the files in the current directory. Check inside the last release folder to see if it had been put there.

It maybe prudent to check if you got the right directory etc setup by changing the CWD to : /tmp

Comment: I tried creating files in /tmp/ with scripts such as **echo "lorem ipsum1" >> /tmp/test.txt** but when logging into the instance afterwards, the file didn't exist, unfortunately. So I'm still at loss.